# How to append the value encoded base64 string in URL in android

Tags: android

I am getting NULL value when appending the encoded base64 String value in URL.

```
    public void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){

    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        imageView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
        bitmapToBase64(bmap);

    } else if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK ) {
        Uri imageUri = data.getData();
        imageView.setImageURI(imageUri);
        imageView.buildDrawingCache();
        Bitmap bmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();
        bitmapToBase64(bmap);

        //Bitmap image = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

    }
}

public String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 70, byteArrayOutputStream);
    byte[] byteArray = byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray();
    String encoderes = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);
    encodestr.setText(encoderes);

    return encoderes;
}
```

Above code is to encode image to base64 String but while appending in URL, String variable encoderes displayed null

```
url="http://10.0.2.2/newz/newz/Mobile_api/photo_decode?photo_encode="+encoderes";
```

Comment: I dont see any code that you save  your `encoderes` to use later?

Comment: String encoderes = Base64.encodeToString(byteArray, Base64.DEFAULT);     Check in above method public String bitmapToBase64(Bitmap bitmap)         I cant access any varaiable out side this method,     getting null value